# Teradata Database 3130 Response limit exceeded?

Tags: teradata

`[Teradata Database] [3130] Response limit exceeded`

I have no idea what is causing this random error message.  It happens when I am making a call to the database for a SELECT or to execute a stored procedure.  I wish I had more information on how to reproduce this, but it appears to be intermittent.

What does this error actually mean?  What types of conditions could cause this?

**Edit:**  I've discovered that the issue goes away when I build my ASP.NET app (vs2012).  It's like something related to connections is being cached somewhere on my machine.  After I recycle the app pool with a rebuild, it resets everything.  The next time this happens, I will try saving the web.config file which automatically recycles the app pool without rebuilding the DLL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a cut&paste from the Messages manual:

> 3130 Response limit exceeded.
>
> Explanation: There is a TDBMS limit of 16 outstanding responses for a
>   single session. If responses are allowed to pile up by an application,
>   this error will occur. A response is the response set from a SELECT
>   statement. A response is kept by the TDBMS until we know the user is
>   done with it at which point it is cancelled. There are two scenarios:
>
> 1. If KeepResp is OFF, the response is automatically cancelled when all rows have been returned to the application and the host has been
>      notified of the end of the response.
> 2. If KeepResp is ON, the response is held until explicitly cancelled by the user. In each case, the response can be explicitly cancelled by
>      the application.as soon as it is no longer needed.
>
> Generated By: Dispatcher.
>
> For Whom: End user.
>
> Remedy: The responses are the property of the session and will
>   automatically automatically be cancelled if the session is logged off.
>   Cancel an old response and resubmit the request or transaction.

As you already noticed this is usually caused by a misbehaving application, too many open result sets on the server side. It's the client's responsibility to close them :-)

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out and it's just not jumping out at me.  Is it a connection leak?  I cannot find anywhere in my app where I am not closing off all connections.  How do you open too many responses?  I use `Using` blocks for all TdConnection, TdCommand, TdDataReader objects.  Doesn't disposal of these objects release any responses?  Edit:  Before I mess with KeepRes, I want to find out why this is happening because I've never had set that property before.

Comment: "How do you open too many responses?" By not closing the previous one :-) I'm not a .Net developer but closing the TdDataReader should close the result set, too.  KeepResp is a CLI option, i don't know how if it exists or how it's called in .NET.

Comment: Marking as answer two years later.  Indeed the reader needs to be closed even after the last row has been retrieved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case error cam when I tried to create more then 15 Statements/Preparedstatements on same Connection Instance & then executedQuery on them.

So you should check that more then 15 Statements are not getting created on same connection or they must get closed before creating another.

Result set is generally out the picture if we are talking about 313 response limit exceed as Statement automatically closes existing resultset in case if it's reused.