# Teradata 3130 Error in JPA/Hiberate context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, teradata

In batch script I use a loop to execute a bunch of sql (hql) against
a Teradata databse. After some iterations I receive the following error:

```
Teradata databse: 3130 Response limit exceeded
```

Now the documentation suggests (as well the answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18903284/teradata-database-3130-response-limit-exceeded)) that this is due to to many open result sets for the same session.

Now the session and the ResultSet are managed by the EntityManager, and I wonder if there is a way to avoid closing and reopening the connection in this case via jpa/hiberate.

I have tried entityManager.clear or flush without any effect.

is there a way to handle this better? maybe I am missing something. My "batch" runes under spring 2.5. in a "cli" mode.

Comment: the 3130 error is not a result size limit error. the documentation suggests to close old result sets due to a limit to the *numer of open result sets*. so i doubt this is due to data size. by the way, data is almost nothing.

Comment: I believe this falls more in teradata side, I would suggest asking someone to remove the extra tags you have for your main post.

Comment: java and jpa tags are appropriate, as the question is about how to pass relevant parameters or close session/result set when connecting not via jdbc but through a jpa api

Comment: as @WeareBorg pointed - this was really an issue with the amount of data. one of rows contained tones of b*ll**it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case it turned out to be a row with large blob data. after refining steps I could retrieve data without 3130 popping out.